# Как подобрать антонимы и синонимы наречия?

Tags: морфология

Правильно-..., скоро-..., вокруг-..., печально-..., верно-..., гладко-..., тихо-...

Answer (score 2):

Синонимы: верно, в мгновение ока, быстро, кругом, грустно, истинно, скользко, бесшумно. Антонимы: ошибочно, нескоро, внутри, весело, неправильно, шершаво, громко.

Answer (score 1):

Вокруг: синонимы — около, кругом, окрест; антоним  — внутри.

Другие слова ищите здесь:

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&word=%CF%F0%E0%E2%E8%EB%FC%ED%FB%E9

Задавайте прилагательные: правильный и т. д.

Answer (score -1):

весело,радостно-грустно